# rotation of line in an android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

i've a math problem, i create a line with each extremety, a perpendicular line but i would like to choose the length of these perpendicular lines but i don't know how to do this :(

this is my code :

```
int vX = fleche.endPoint.x - fleche.startPoint.x;
        int vY = fleche.endPoint.y - fleche.startPoint.y;

        int vXP = - ( fleche.endPoint.y - fleche.startPoint.y );

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(fleche.color);
        p.setTextSize(30);
        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        p.setStrokeWidth(8);
        p.setAlpha(fleche.alpha);

        Path path = new Path();

        path.moveTo(fleche.startPoint.x - 10,fleche.startPoint.y - 10);
        path.lineTo(fleche.endPoint.x - 10, fleche.endPoint.y - 10);
        c.drawTextOnPath(fleche.value + fleche.unit, path, 30, 0, p);

        c.drawPath(path, p);

        path.moveTo(fleche.startPoint.x - 10,fleche.startPoint.y - 10);
        path.lineTo(fleche.endPoint.x - 10, fleche.endPoint.y - 10);
        c.drawTextOnPath(fleche.value + fleche.unit, path, 30, 0, p);

        //ligne principale
        c.drawLine(fleche.startPoint.x, fleche.startPoint.y, fleche.endPoint.x, fleche.endPoint.y, p);

        //left
        c.drawLine(fleche.startPoint.x, fleche.startPoint.y, fleche.startPoint.x + vXP, fleche.startPoint.y + vX, p);
        c.drawLine(fleche.startPoint.x, fleche.startPoint.y, fleche.startPoint.x - vXP, fleche.startPoint.y - vX, p);

        //right
        c.drawLine(fleche.endPoint.x, fleche.endPoint.y, fleche.endPoint.x + vXP, fleche.endPoint.y + vX, p);
        c.drawLine(fleche.endPoint.x, fleche.endPoint.y, fleche.endPoint.x - vXP, fleche.endPoint.y - vX, p);
        //Tools.logDebug("Fleche créée(" + i + "/" +  (arrows.size()-1) +  ") :" + fleche.toString());
```

Thanks in advance to all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can scale `dx` and `dy` to length L:

```
float ratio = L / Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
dx *= ratio;
dy *= ratio;
```

edit after comment:

```
//left
final float L = 20.0f; // for instance
final float ratio = L / Math.sqrt(vXP * vXP + vX * vX);
final float dx = vXP * ratio;
final float dy = vX * ratio;
c.drawLine(fleche.startPoint.x, fleche.startPoint.y, fleche.startPoint.x + dx, fleche.startPoint.y + dy, p);
c.drawLine(fleche.startPoint.x, fleche.startPoint.y, fleche.startPoint.x - dx, fleche.startPoint.y - dy, p);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but what represent dx and dy??